# Error "DB Error: no such field" when trying to migrate from old version of Civi on Joomla to newest version on Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, joomla

I'm currently working on Joomla 1.5 with Civi 3.4. I need to migrate to Wordpress, so I created a fresh install of Wordpress 4.4 locally and installed a fresh version of Civi 4.7. This all worked just fine. Then when I tried to merge the old database with the new one (I left out the civicrm_domain, civicrm_website, and civicrm_cache tables (using the ones from the new install instead of the old) because leaving those in broke Civi entirely), I got the following error:

DB Error: no such field

```
Fatal error: Uncaught CRM_Core_Exception: [0: Transaction integrity error: Expected to find active frame thrown in C:\wamp\www\fca4\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\Civi\Core\Transaction\Manager.php on line 107
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0007  315512  {main}( )   ..\admin.php:0
2   0.3569  35431152    do_action( )    ..\admin.php:236
3   0.3569  35432664    call_user_func_array:{C:\wamp\www\fca4\wp-includes\plugin.php:525} ( )  ..\plugin.php:525
4   0.3569  35432968    CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke( )    ..\plugin.php:525
5   0.3575  35439152    CiviCRM_For_WordPress_Users->sync_user( )   ..\civicrm.php:1197
6   0.3577  35439408    CRM_Core_BAO_UFMatch::synchronize( )    ..\civicrm.users.php:179
7   0.3578  35440424    CRM_Core_BAO_UFMatch::synchronizeUFMatch( ) ..\UFMatch.php:118
8   0.3617  35559312    CRM_Contact_BAO_Contact::createProfileContact( )    ..\UFMatch.php:300
9   0.3856  37549080    CRM_Contact_BAO_Contact::create( )  ..\Contact.php:1897
10  0.4439  41554552    CRM_Contact_BAO_Contact_Utils::clearContactCaches( )    ..\Contact.php:440
11  0.4483  42007680    CRM_Contact_BAO_GroupContactCache::remove( )    ..\Utils.php:914
12  0.4489  42008896    CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery( )   ..\GroupContactCache.php:386
13  0.4489  42011456    CRM_Core_DAO->query( )  ..\DAO.php:1267
14  0.4489  42011456    DB_DataObject->query( ) ..\DAO.php:334
15  0.4489  42011456    DB_DataObject->_query( )    ..\DataObject.php:1627
16  0.4490  42012160    DB_common->query( ) ..\DataObject.php:2435
17  0.4490  42012288    DB_mysql->simpleQuery( )    ..\common.php:1216
18  0.4492  42012320    DB_mysql->mysqlRaiseError( )    ..\mysql.php:328
19  0.4492  42012928    DB_common->raiseError( )    ..\mysql.php:895
20  0.4492  42013808    PEAR->raiseError( ) ..\common.php:1905
21  0.4493  42014584    DB_Error->DB_Error( )   ..\PEAR.php:564
22  0.4493  42020648    PEAR_Error->PEAR_Error( )   ..\DB.php:976
23  0.4494  42061896    call_user_func:{C:\wamp\www\fca4\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\packages\PEAR.php:931} ( )  ..\PEAR.php:931
24  0.4494  42062488    CRM_Core_Error::handle( )   ..\PEAR.php:931
25  0.5120  42377920    CRM_Core_Error::abend( )    ..\Error.php:250
26  0.5185  42377088    CRM_Utils_System::civiExit( )   ..\Error.php:958
```

There shouldn't be any tables missing so I'm not sure what's wrong.